# Dataflow worker install python library without NAT

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam

In my GCP project Cloud NAT is disabled, so dataflow worker wont be able to communicate outside internet.
As `google-cloud-storage` is not a default library in dataflow worker.

ref: https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/docs/concepts/sdk-worker-dependencies#beam-2x-python

Wondering if there is a hack to install it on worker node during the runtime.

My `setup.py` file looks like this:

```
import setuptools
setuptools.setup(
    name='x_pipelines',
    version='1.0.0',
    install_requires=["google-cloud-storage"],
    packages=setuptools.find_packages(),
)
```

Answer (score 0):

have you tried [using Custom Containers](https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/docs/guides/using-custom-containers)?

You would create a container with a Dockerfile like so:

```
FROM apache/beam_python3.8_sdk:2.34.0

RUN pip install $DEPENDENCIES
```

And then you can publish this container to GCR, which later you can tell Dataflow to use: `--sdk_container_image=$IMAGE_URI`